# Kafka - key specific subscription using many partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with ~100k discrete keys. Using manual partition assignment, I'd like to be able to able to get as close as possible to being able to subscribe for an individual key.

In these blog articles ([a](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/), [b](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-supports-200k-partitions-per-cluster)) Confluent say that 200k partitions are supported, but only recommend 4k partitions per broker.

Question is, is there anything else I can do to either support more partitions (aside from adding more brokers).

Alternatively, are there some patterns for supporting subscription by key in Kafka?

Comment: Why you are looking partition per key..why not group key per partitions

Comment: Assume for a moment that you only have a single partition, and 1 consumer for all messages in that partition. When the consumer processes a message, you can get the key for the message that it is currently processing, so I'm assuming it could handle anything specific to that key as needed, like a method takes a parameter. What does your logic do that would you require a consumer per key?

Comment: @KevinHooke ~10k of the 100k keys might have 10e6 messages per day. If a consumer is not interested in those keys, I don't want the network carrying those events to the consumer, and I don't want the consumers wasting cycles deserialising keys just to throw the event away.

Comment: You could use the Streams API to filter messages with keys known to high volume (if you know that) to a separate stream for processing by one consumer group, and the rest can be consumed by another consumer group?